# Where can I find a driver for a specific HP printer?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, printer, hp-laserjet

I would like to install a driver for HP LaserJet 4250n on a Windows 7 machine. The HP site gives me a universal driver which is not what I need. After installing that driver, I have a new icon in Devices and Printers, "HP Universal Printing PCL6". When I choose this "printer" after clicking Ctrl+P, a window opens in which I can input the address of the actual printer I want to use. It does work in that the printer prints the things I need, but it's twice as much clicking as I'd like. Can't I just install a driver for the actual printer I'm using? Where can I find it?

Comment: Maybe you can set some preferences in the properties page of that "virtual" printer?

Comment: How are you adding the printer exactly to Windows?  The printer is a network printer, which means, you should be adding the printer my the ip address.  **The type of driver you think you want does not exist for the pritner you have.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how you install the driver itself, in your case "traditional mode" is the way to go.

I got this from the "HP Universal Print Driver" [manual](http://h20331.www2.hp.com/Hpsub/downloads/UPD5_guide_final,%20web.pdf):

> Because the HP Universal Print Driver is flexible, you can install it in Traditional or Dynamic mode—and you can 
>   have both running on your PC at once.
>   Traditional mode functions exactly like the product-specific drivers you are accustomed to using.
>   When installed 
>   in Traditional mode, the HP Universal Print Driver is associated with a specific print device, which you can then 
>   select from an application’s Print menu. Once selected, the 
>   driver functions as a traditional, product-specific driver.

Answer (score 0):

This one should work. I remember having to use vista drivers for win 7 in the past with no issues http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareDescription.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodTypeId=18972&prodSeriesId=412144&prodNameId=412158&swEnvOID=2093&swLang=8&mode=2&taskId=135&swItem=lj-24656-6

The driver for that printer for win7 is actually included with windows as standard, so you should really use that.